# Trying to call a handler on a custom element not working

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to click on `<GroupsRow />` and have that call a function so I can use the index to change a property. Yet my click never fires `handler()`.

```
export default class GroupsContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
  }

  handler(index) {
    console.log(index)
  }


  _repeatGroupRows(tags) {
    return tags.map((tag, index) =>
      <GroupsRow key={index} tag={tag} onClick={this.handler.bind(this, index)} />
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="groups-list-wrapper">
        <GroupsHeader />
        {this._repeatGroupRows(this.props.state.tags)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: do you get any errors? i think you should bind `_repeatGroupRows` to the `class` (in the `constructor`) by the way you should that for `this.handler` as well for performance sake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not post the code for `GroupsRow` component but my guess is that you don't call this handler inside this component.
`GroupsRow` should call the `props.onClick` handler as it's a react element and not a "normal" DOM element.

Answer (score 1):

The `map` function does not preserve context, so `this` will not be what you expect and `this.handler` will be undefined.

`map` does accept a second argument for this exact purpose though.  It should look like this;

```
_repeatGroupRows(tags) {
    return tags.map((tag, index) => {
      return <GroupsRow key={index} tag={tag} onClick={this.handler.bind(this, index)} />
    }, this);
  }
```

EDIT: @lustoykov is correct in his answer that this is not the problem due to the fact that a bind is used.  Bit of tunnel vision on my part, as I see a lot of people failing to use both the bind and `thisArg`, but that's not the issue this time!

Comment: for performance sake all the binding should be done in the constructor and not inside the render method (which will create a new instance of a function) not to mention inside loops

Comment: I agree, but that section was just copy pasted.  I'm simply adding on the `thisArg` argument to the map function.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at the wrong place. The example definitely works, [here](https://jsfiddle.net/lustoykov/69z2wepo/85639/) is a very similar version.

---

**EDIT:** I think @Sag1v nails it - in this case `onClick` is just a property passed to the `<GroupsRow />`. In the root element (probably `<div />`) of the component, you'd have to do pass it once again:

```
<div onClick={this.props.onClick} />
```

PS. @gravityplanx - he doesn't need `this` context for the `map` function, since the arrow function reuses the context of the parent.

Comment: I was a bit off as well :-)